# MFC, C++, View, View Resources

Tags: mfc

I'm going through [THIS TUTORIAL](http://depts.washington.edu/cmmr/biga/chapter_tutorials/1.C++_MFC_D3DOGL/1.StepByStepGuide/index.html) On MFC

Lesson 2 states:

```
  Clean Up UI Window
  (Inside the VS Project Window) Click the menu item View >> Resource View
```

I click on `View`

A list of options drops down

The option *Resource View*  does not appear on my list.  I'll cut-and-paste a screen shot of that menu below.

Where do I click ?

Screen shot from Microsoft Visual Studio, Version 10.0.40219.1

Microsoft Net Framework Version 4.5.50938

[image: MFC C++ "View" drop down menu]

Comment: What version and edition of Visual Studio do you have?

Comment: Visual Studio 2010, Version 10.0.40219.1  (I think I copied it properly) I will edit my original post

Comment: @BenVoigt  Wo, just looked a little more closely.  That tutorial was written for Visual Studio 2003.  I'm using 2010.  I'm now trying to change the "ID" and I can't find it. The more I look, the more I wonder if I should try to do this tutorial. Advice from experts is welcome

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's under *View - Other Windows - Resource View*